# Error in ConfusionMatrix: data and reference should be factors with the same levels

Tags: r, classification, data-science, confusion-matrix

I get this error from the confusionMatrix:

> data and reference should be factors with the same levels.

Here is the code I used:

```
index <- createDataPartition(glass$Type, p = 0.7, list = F)

train <- glass[index, ]
test <- glass[-index, ]

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number =5, repeats = 3)

knn_fit <- train(Type ~., data = train, method = "knn", 
                 preProcess= c("center", "scale"),
                 trControl=ctrl, tuneGrid=data.frame(k=4:17))


pred_knn <- predict(knn_fit, newdata = test)

confusionMatrix(dat=pred_knn, reference = test$Type)

**str(pred_knn)**
*> str(pred_knn)
 num [1:63] 1 1.75 1 1 1 1.5 1 2.5 1 1.5 ...*


**str(test$Type)**
*> str(test$Type)
 int [1:63] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...*
```

I already tried to remodel pred_knn into as.integer(pred_knn) put it is not working. Do they have to have the same values in their? And how can I work this out?

Comment: You should always indicate what packages you have loaded since the functions you are using are not part of base R. I'm guessing the `caret` package? What kind of predictions does `method="knn" make? It appears they are numeric since `pred_knn` is a numeric vector. A confusion matrix assumes the data are categorical so when it converts your numeric predictions to your integer Types, the factors do not match. If a predicted glass Type of 1.75 is not meaningful, you should be using a method other than `knn`.

Comment: HI @dcarlson 

Okay thank you for the info and your answer! yes i'm using the `caret` package. Okay i will try another model and let you know if it worked - what method would you recommend? 

Best Cenk

Comment: You should ask for recommendations regarding statistical matters on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). This list is for technical questions about implementing particular methods. You will have to provide more details about your data and what you are trying to accomplish.